# About using python sockets with kivy for an android app

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, buildozer

Is there anything I should know about? I'm currently through some buildozer problems, but I guess it's because I messed up the installation of all dependencies related to it.

Like, if my `main.py` imports from kivy, socket and threading, in the `buildozer.spec`, should I state the requirements line to also require socket and threading alongside kivy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. like this one:

```
requirements = kivy,pyjnius
```

I'm using the pyjnius module so I need to state it in my buildozer.spec's requirements line.

Comment: so, to confirm, my requirements line would be:

`requirements = kivy, threading, socket`
?

Comment: thanks dude, i've been looking for the answer for the last 24 hours and found nothing, which led for my first formal question posted here. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to add `threading` and `socket` to your requirements, as these are included with python's standard library.

Comment: @inclement, Thanks for the info.                                                          José Gabriel Alvez, you can uncheck my answer since I was wrong.